# How to add menu items separators programmatically on Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I have a mainmenu on my Form and I want to be able to insert separator to it programmatically not during design time. I went through context popup menu for the mainmenu that lists all the available properties and did not find anything that will allow me to insert separator. Google wasn't much of a help. So, how is this done in Delphi on Windows? I am using Delphi 2010.

I simply want to do something like the following but `AddSeparator` command doesn't exist:

```
MainMenu1.Items[5].AddSeparator;
```

Comment: There you go http://pastebin.com/gChvPgy6.

Comment: Or this one might be handy http://pastebin.com/ZedAbjTn...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a new menu item and set its caption to `'-'`.

```
var
  MenuItem: TMenuItem;
....
MenuItem := TMenuItem.Create(Menu); // Menu is the menu into which you are adding
MenuItem.Caption := '-';
Menu.Items.Add(MenuItem);
```

Instead of `Add`, which adds to the end of the menu, you can use `Insert` to insert the item into the middle of the menu.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.Caption) says:

> Specify a hyphen character (-) as the value of Caption for the menu item to indicate that the menu item is a separator.